# Could we talk about the same meaning?

Tags: past-perfect, gerunds

1. Entering the room, he saw her, where he had left her.
2. When he entered the room, he saw her, he had left her.

I would like to know if these statements means the same thing and are interchangeable.

Comment: The second example is not grammatical and it is difficult to guess what you mean. Why did you write it that way, and was it meant to be the same meaning as 1?

Comment: In 1., the second comma is unnecessary other than for emphasis: "Entering the room, he saw her where he had left her."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is grammatically correct, if rather awkward and stilted. It indicates that he saw her in the same place she had been when he had left.

The second sentence is not correct. It appears to say that he saw her when he entered the room, then switches to discussing their relationship status. Her location is not referenced at any point.

A native would probably write: "He saw her as he entered the room, right where he had left her."